# Restoring Division Implementation in C++ Using Bitwise Operators

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, division

I'm trying to implement [the restoring division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Restoring_division), but I keep getting incorrect results. The trick is my assignment requires I implement +,-,*,/,% using only bitwise operators, loops, and branches. I've successfully implemented `add(a,b)`, `sub(a,b)`, and `mul(a,b)`, hence their use in my `div(a,b,&rem)` method. Here's the code,

```
template<typename T>
T div(T dividend, T divisor, T &remainder){
    unsigned q = 1;
    unsigned n = mul(sizeof(T), CHAR_BIT);
    remainder = dividend;
    divisor <<= n;

    for(int i=sub(n,1); i>=0; i=sub(i,1)) {
        remainder = sub(remainder << 1, divisor);
        if(remainder < 0) {
            q &= ~(1 << i);  // set i-th bit to 0
            remainder = add(remainder, divisor);
        } else {
            q |= 1 << i;     // set i-th bit to 1
        }
    }
    return q;
}
```

I've tested all the edge cases and common examples for `add`, `sub`, and `mul` and I know they work correctly for any integer input.

It appears that for any input I get `q = -1` and `remainder = 0`. I think the problem has something to do with the signing of `T`, or `q` and `n`. I think my implementation is the same, is there a reason why the method is returning `-1` and `0`?

Comment: What type are the parameters? Did you notice the comment in the Wikipedia code: **P and D need twice the word width of N and Q**

Comment: @Barmar In my implementation `T` is a short

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the algorithm a bit closer.  Your `if(q < 0)` comparison is using the wrong variable.  It should be `if (remainder < 0)`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't catch, however,  I'm still getting incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned this could have to do with signing of `T`, or `q` and `n`.  You also mentioned in a comment that your implementation of T is a `short`.

Referring to the https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types,

Your type T is always at least `16` bits but the intermediate values in shown `div` function are `unsigned`, or `int`, in general, which could be `32` bits depending on data model.

So your returned value is being truncated into the potentially smaller size of the `T` type holder to produce an expected result.